# Is there a Windows 10 equivalent tool that does the job of Apple Configurator mobile device management?

Tags: windows-10, mdm, apple-configurator

The Apple Configurator tool is a MacOS application that allows you to create and edit a device profile, which can be downloaded from a webserver and used to suitably configure devices in the Apple ecosystem.

Does an equivalent tool exist for the Microsoft ecosystem?

Most specifically, is there a Windows 10 compatible Windows application that generates a suitable device profile, that can be downloaded from a webserver and used to suitably configure devices in the Microsoft ecosystem?

Answer (score -1):

There are quite many similar tools for Windows 10. Windows 10 has its own MDM solution and has distinct features. There is another good Mobile Device Management Solution for Windows 10 application i.e [**MobiLock Pro**](https://mobilock.in/mobile-device-management). It's more simplified and easy to use compared to other MDM for Windows 10.

Comment: "Windows 10 has its own MDM solution" - do you have details of that this solution is called, and a link to its documentation?

Comment: @Graham Leggett, You may check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/. However, customized solutions like MobiLock Pro Windows 10 MDM (https://mobilock.in/windows-mdm-solution)
 are quite simplified and can be managed and used conveniently as per requirements with much less cost and effort comparatively.